# Check if a FieldInfo is an class object, or a value (string, int, etc.)

Tags: c#

Edit: I've got a solution, I worded my question badly due to completely missunadesting how classes are categorized, e.g string being a class, silly me.

I've settle on specifying data types, as follows:

```
if (f.FieldType != typeof(string) && f.FieldType != typeof(int))
{
   //do something A
}
else
{
   //do something B
}
```

OG Question:

I need to loop through the fields of an object, and if the field is another object do something different than if its a base value type like a string.

I've tried .IsClass, but this is true even when its an int, bool, etc.

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfoList = fooObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (FieldInfo f in fieldInfoList)
{
   if (f.FieldType.IsClass)
   {
      //do something A
   }
   else
   {
       //do something B
   }
}
```

So if I have the following classes, while looping through the fields of 'Foo' I want it to do something "A" for "FooName" and "FooThing", but do something "B" for "BarLevel".

```
public class Foo
{
   public string FooName { get; set; }
   public int FooThing { get; set; }
   public Bar BarLevel { get; set; }            
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarName { get; set; }
    public string BarSomething { get; set; }
    public string BarYoda { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `string` isn't a value type.  It's a class, which is a reference type.

Comment: Yeah as Servy pointed out, `string` is a class type.  So your code is working exactly as you want it to except that `FooName` will do something "B" since it is also a class type.

Comment: @Servy K? So how do I distinguish between a string a FieldInfo and my Bar FieldInfo?

Comment: Are the classes you're looking for always going to be defined in the same assembly as this code that's running? If so, this is quite easy. You can just do something like `Assembly.GetAssembly(f.FieldType) == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. If not, it's a bit more tricky because you have to use process of elimination. You'll have to rule out primitives (`string`, `int`, etc.), structs (`DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, etc.), obviously make sure `IsClass` is `true`, and potentially some other things I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Comment: @Vereonix What are you going to do with each of them that requires you to distinguish them?  You just say you want to split classes and value types, and you have the code for that.  If you want something else, you'll need to describe what you actually want.

Comment: @Jesse hmmm I need to compare multiple appSettings to each other (I'm deserialising them) and determine if any values differ from a master copy. Seeing as its an appsetting the final data values will either be string or int I think (except for the nested objects), so I guess I can get away with explicitly specifying data types

Comment: @Vereonix Sounds like your types should be overriding `Equals` to have some different behavior than the default, if your goal is to determine if two of these objects are equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, you're trying to achieve the following if/else.

```
if (f.FieldType.Name == "String" || f.FieldType.IsPrimitive)
{
    // built-in types
}
else
{
    // others
}
```